# Find the missing chemical structures in the reaction sequence

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis, carbohydrates, reagents

I came across the following question, where a set of reagents are used, starting from a carbohydrate derivative.
[image]
I understand that this is some total synthesis reaction, but I cannot find which one.

1. Please explain the structures of A, B, C, D, and E. A clear mechanism would be greatly appreciated. (If you get the original research paper, it would be very helpful)
2. From the total synthesis of reserpine and morphine that I have studied, Acetic anhydride is used for esterification. But, since there are three -OH groups here, will there be any selectivity in the esterification?

Ref: Reserpine total synthesis - /https://renaud.dcb.unibe.ch/journal-club/journal-club-2015/p2015_23-reserpine---woodwa.pdf (page-10)

Comment: Don't worry about selctive acetylation, you have excess acetic anhydride in the first reaction so that is designed to acetylate all three alcohols.

Comment: This may help you with the second reaction  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azide-alkyne_Huisgen_cycloaddition

Comment: You shouldn't search for some random synthesis, but specific reactions.